# How to access the ith column of a Javascript Multidimensional Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

For e.g if the array looks like this

```
var example = [[2, "Dwayne"], [4, "Mark"], [8, "Jeff"]];
```

I want to get the 2nd value of each array inside example array e.g values like this:

```
"Dwayne", "Mark", "Jeff"
```

Comment: `example.map(v => v[1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to construct the desired output.

*You must be careful about the index however i.e data in that index should exists in the input array otherwise you will get `undefined`.*

```js
const example = [[2, "Dwayne"], [4, "Mark"], [8, "Jeff"]];

const getValuesByIndex = (arr, i) => arr.map(a => a[i]);

console.log(getValuesByIndex(example, 1));
console.log(getValuesByIndex(example, 0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for-loop` to iterate the array.

```js
const example = [
  [2, "Dwayne"],
  [4, "Mark"],
  [8, "Jeff"]
];
for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  console.log(example[i][1]);
}
```

In this case `i` selects the array within the array and `1` returns index 1 (the name).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to complete it:

1. You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array from the original array without mutating its data.
2. use [`Destructuring_assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to destruct each item. After that, you can get the item you want.

```js
var example = [[2,"Dwayne"],[4,"Mark"], [8,"Jeff"]];
var result = example.map(([item1, item2]) => item2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, to store the resultant array in the code you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map). On the other hand, take into account you can access the different dimensions of your array with the corresponding dimension index `[index]`, like this:

```js
const example = [
  [2, "Dwayne"],
  [4, "Mark"],
  [8, "Jeff"]
];

for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  console.log(example[i][1]);
}
```